# change default file format when saving pictures by MS Paint

Tags: windows-8

Each time when I try to saving a picture by MS Paint, the default format is .png, but I want .jpeg, How can I set .jpeg as default format when saving pictures from MS Paint? I save pictures quite often, I don't want to change the format every time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing to do with programming

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at this Windows Forum [Post](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-pictures/how-to-change-default-save-as-type-in-ms-paint/f01ce17c-274a-416b-ad7d-7c54c54e642e). What it does is create a quick access link that will default the Save File dialog to jpeg, you would then click this icon to save your file as jpeg.

From Link:

> Open PAINT, then click the BLUE drop down box in the top left hand
>   corner of the screen (this is the box that gives the drop down options
>   for saving a file), now click SAVE AS and a selection of save as
>   formats including JPEG will appear to the right, move your cursor over
>   the JPEG option and RIGHT CLICK (not left click), three options will
>   be presented, click (select) the top option which says ADD TO QUICK
>   ACCESS FOLDER.  This creates a new ICON at the top of the paint screen
>   next to the DO and UNDO arrows (icons).

Comment: This method does not work with the version of Paint that comes with Windows 11 (Paint 11.2301.22.0). Right-clicking on the menu does nothing.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the answer by [mark-hall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479512/mark-hall):

As the author [zdd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1487475/zdd) asked for a keyboard shortcut to save the file as jpeg, you can now use keyboard shortcut ALT + 4 (if the icon is at the 4th place).

Answer (score -1):

there should be a better version too:

1. Create a blank jpg image and save it into a permanent folder somewhere
2. Right-click the image, select Properties and set it to Read-only
3. Search for Paint in the main Windows menu (not mspaint!!!)
4. Right-click on the Paint shortcut and select Properties
5. in the Target field, replace it with this line:

   ```
   %windir%\system32\mspaint.exe "C:\Users\username\Documents\default1.jpg"
   ```
6. every time you want to save something as .jpg, search for Paint(not mspaint!!) in the main menu and you are good to go!
7. in addition, you can also add the JPG shortcut into the Paint quick access toolbar as described by others

Comment: LOL!

i found out that it actually works 100% !! you just need to type in "paint" into the search/run box, not "mspaint" !! (and you cant make the same shortcut to mspaint.exe)